# Populating a two dimensional Swift array using append vs element by element

Tags: arrays, swift, append

Using Apple Swift: I have a very large two dimensional String array from, for example, a .cdl file. I then build a Double array from the String array such that I now have a String array (variableData) and a Double array (variableDataDouble). Now I want to adjust the values in the Double array.

If I use append and the String array, the adjustment is fast.

```
cdlVariablesDictionary[eachVariable]?.variableDataDouble.removeAll()
for rows in 0 ..< rowsCount {
     var tempArray: [Double] = []
     for columns in 0 ..< columnsCount {
         var adjustedValue: Double =  Double((cdlVariablesDictionary[eachVariable]?.variableData[rows][columns])!)!
         adjustedValue = adjustedValue * scaleNumeric + offsetNumeric
         tempArray.append(adjustedValue)
     }
     cdlVariablesDictionary[eachVariable]?.variableDataDouble.append(tempArray)
}
```

If I make adjustments to each value in the Double array, the adjustment is very, very slow.

```
for rows in 0 ..< rowsCount {
     for columns in 0 ..< columnsCount {
          var adjustedValue: Double = (cdlVariablesDictionary[eachVariable]?.variableDataDouble[rows][columns])!
          adjustedValue = adjustedValue * scaleNumeric + offsetNumeric
          cdlVariablesDictionary[eachVariable]?.variableDataDouble[rows][columns] = adjustedValue
     }
}
```

Why is the append method fast and the element by element method very, very slow?

Comment: Swift uses copy-on-write so in the second instances, it may have keep on allocating new memory with each assignment. Run your code through the Profiler and check if that's the case. You can also try copying `variableDataDouble` into a separate variable, make all your data manipulation and then assign it back to `cdlVariablesDictionary[eachVariable]`

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.